# Building prediction model using only one or two features

Tags: python, classification, prediction

i have data as shown below

df.head()

```
name    location    duration month  status
aim          bgy                12  active
terra        pm                 3   inactive
jerry        bgy                23  inactive
finn         dm                  8  active
pearl        bgy                21  active
doe          pm                  9  inactive
pearl        pm                 11  inactive
```

almost 2000 data points i have and around 6 unique location names. i need to build/train a prediction model where given any name,location , present duration details it should predict the status(active/inactive) with the probability%
so if the input to this model is

```
name    location    duration month  
jim          bgy                6   
tim          pm                 9   
sara         bgy                12
```

i should get results like

```
name    location    duration month  status  active_probability
jim          bgy                6   active   0.9
tim          pm                 9   inactive 0.0
sara         bgy                12  active   0.8
```

Comment: why don't you just try it?

Comment: Use predict_proba in sklearn to get the probabilistic score.. check this out.. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22762/understanding-predict-proba-from-multioutputclassifier

Comment: @FlorianH...hi.. i tried using gradient boost algo. but i was getting error related to less feature

Comment: @Bhaskar.. i went through the link you have shared. i am new to sklearn and model building. X, y1 = make_classification(n_samples=5, n_features=2, n_informative=1, n_classes=2, random_state=1)
y2 = shuffle(y1, random_state=1)
Y = np.vstack((y1, y2)).T . based on my data how do i get X and Y here?

Comment: @aim.. I wiould recommend you to go through this link for better understanding on machine learning..   https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/09/common-machine-learning-algorithms/

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with LightGBM. It's very easy to use and it runs very fast.

Comment: I am new to classification. please let me know how to apply this on the data that i have. like the steps required

Comment: suggest you refer to the docs [https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python-API.html](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python-API.html)

Comment: This is not a right place to get someone to write ready code for you, This is a very simple model, where you can use the number of great gradient boosting packages, such as xgboost, lightgbm, catboost, etc. Find related modules on github - there are plenty of code example to direct you to solve your current issue.